# Preprocessor defined name for x64 platform in MSDEV2010

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, preprocessor

Are there any preprocessor definitions that will let me know if the build environment is targeting X64?

I need a context similar to `#ifdef _DEBUG`, only I want to test the platform, not the release mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, it's listed in the [predefined macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) documentation.

Comment: I love how VS shows my code grayed like it's not defined, but at runtime it is actually defined...

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: _WIN64
I've been searching MSDN for hours and finally when I post a question on here, I find it...